# Trying to populate dropdowns menu each time when cloning the form using Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, clone

My form is able to be cloned each time when I push a new form instance to the array. But each time when I select some value on the parent form, the selected value in child form also updated. I have read non parent-children communication on Vuejs website but still confused. Another important thing I noticed is I have to declare the options array outside of the form data scope. I used vue-multiselect library for dropdowns.

The goal is to block parent and children communication. so they don't update synchronously.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
   Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
 },
  data: {
    people: [{
         value: []
    }],
    options: [
        { name: 'Vue.js', language: 'JavaScript' },
        { name: 'Rails', language: 'Ruby' },
        { name: 'Sinatra', language: 'Ruby' },
        { name: 'Laravel', language: 'PHP', $isDisabled: true },
        { name: 'Phoenix', language: 'Elixir' }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.6"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.6/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(person, index) in people">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form__label">index number for the form {{ index }}</label><br>

      <label class="typo__label">Single select / dropdown</label>
      <multiselect v-model="value" deselect-label="Can't remove this value" track-by="name" label="name" placeholder="Select one" :options="options" :searchable="false" :allow-empty="false"></multiselect>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button" @click="people.push({value: ''})">Add</button>
    <button class="button" @click="people.pop()">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your code in your post and not just a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're rather copying the current element as is by passing an empty value to `people` array in order for the `v-for` to re-run, so it's rendering with the selected value without resetting the inner value of the list, because in theory you're merely replicating the current element instead of creating a new one. So your solution would be to either forcibly set the `options` value for the newly created list. Or rather actually create a whole new template and push it to the DOM - Which is the best solution IMO.

Answer (score 0):

In

```html
<multiselect v-model="value" ...
```

You are binding all `<multiselect>`s to the same `value`.

You have to bind each `<multiselect>` to its respective `person` (because `person` is the variable of the `v-for="(person, index) in people"`.

For example, you could bind each `<multiselect>` to the `person.value`:

```
<multiselect v-model="person.value" ...
```

Demo below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
   Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
 },
  data: {
    people: [{
         value: []
    }],
    options: [
        { name: 'Vue.js', language: 'JavaScript' },
        { name: 'Rails', language: 'Ruby' },
        { name: 'Sinatra', language: 'Ruby' },
        { name: 'Laravel', language: 'PHP', $isDisabled: true },
        { name: 'Phoenix', language: 'Elixir' }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
* { font-size: small; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.6"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.6/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(person, index) in people">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form__label">index number for the form {{ index }}</label><br>

      <label class="typo__label">Single select / dropdown</label>
      <multiselect v-model="person.value" deselect-label="Can't remove this value" track-by="name" label="name" placeholder="Select one" :options="options" :searchable="false" :allow-empty="false"></multiselect>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button" @click="people.push({value: ''})">Add</button>
    <button class="button" @click="people.pop()">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```